# FINDSTR - add "date modified" of the files as a prefix to each result

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm looking for some commands to add to my script.
The script goes through a folder of text log files and looks for a string passed as input.
Unfortunately, the log files overflow at a set size and don't have their date in the file name, just a number suffix and a string prefix. In the log file lines there is only the time of the event, not the date. The date is added as a single line at 12 o'clock.

Example of the file folder where the search is done:

> Logfile_001.txt
>   Logfile_002.txt
>   Reboot-01_Logfile_001.txt
>   Reboot-01_Logfile_002.txt
>   Reboot-01_Logfile_003.txt
>   Reboot-02_Logfile_001.txt
>   Reboot-02_Logfile_002.txt

**I want to add the "date modified" attribute of the searched file in each line of the FINDSTR result.**

My current code:

```
@ECHO off
DEL /F _Result.searchresult
SET /P searchterm=Enter search term: 
@ECHO Searching for %searchterm% >_Result.searchresult
@ECHO --------------------------------------------- >>_Result.searchresult
FINDSTR /S /C:"%searchterm%" *.txt >>_Result.searchresult
_Result.searchresult
```

Current result:

> Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:29:05.586    loginfo 
>   Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:30:05.586    loginfo

Wanted result:

> 2019/08/13 Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:29:05.586 loginfo
>   2019/08/13 Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:30:05.586 loginfo

Or:

> Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:2019/08/13 08:29:05.586 loginfo
>   Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:2019/08/13 08:30:05.586 loginfo

Where "2019/08/13" is the date of the "date modified" attribute of file Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt

Comment: Instead of `findstr /S ...` try this as a basis: `for %%I in ("*.txt") do (echo %%~tI:& findstr /C:"%searchterm%" "%%~I") >> "_Result.searchresult"`

Comment: @aschipfl Thank you for your help. This suggestion results in a line showing the attribute and then below the FINDSTR lines without filename. It is already better to see the date of all the results. It is not the wanted result of the question, where each FINDSTR result has the attribute in the line.

Comment: You're welcome! As said my suggestion was just intended as a basis to work on; the file name could be returned explicitly by `echo/%%~I` in the loop body; to combine everything to a single line nest a `for /F` loop that captures the `findstr` output, like this, for instance: `(for %%I in ("*.txt") do for /F "delims=" %%S in ('findstr /C:"%searchterm%" "%%~I"') do for /F %%T in ("%%~tI") do echo %%T:%%~nxI:%%S) >> "_Result.searchresult"` (the second `for /F` loop tries to split off the pure date from the `%%~tI` portion, but regard that this value is locale-dependent!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OP I had to make a minor Change as I wrote this on my phone on the train originally and I made a couple typos etc. that were present when you tested

**Specifically these two single character changes:**

> `"Tokens=1*`  NOT `"Token=1*`

and

> `SET "_DateMatched=1"` NOT `SET "_DateMatched="`

To do this split out the file name from the results of find string using a loop and then get the date from that to use in the echo.

### Script

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ResultFile=_Result.searchresult"
  SET "_DateMatched="
)
DEL /F /Q "%_ResultFile%"
SET /P "_SearchTerm=Enter search term: "

ECHO Searching for %_SearchTerm% >"%_ResultFile%"
ECHO --------------------------------------------- >>"%_ResultFile%"

FOR /F "Tokens=1* delims=:"  %%A IN ('
  FINDSTR /S /C:"%_SearchTerm%" *.txt
')  DO (
  For %%a in ( %%~tA ) Do (
    IF NOT DEFINED _DateMatched (
      ECHO.%%a %%A:%%B>>"%_ResultFile%"
      SET "_DateMatched=1"
    )
  )
  SET "_DateMatched="
)
```

### Results

```
Searching for ggg 
--------------------------------------------- 
 08/13/2019 test.txt:ggg
 08/13/2019 test2.txt:ggg
```

In addition, Yes you could use a FOR /F instead it was a 50/50 coin flip II didd to use the defined/not defined with a FOR loop instead of a FOR /F loop.

However the other answer provided chose this path, but for some reason used my code as a base and added in a 3rd loop so that their middle loop is redundant.

I'll post that alternative here as well as I had thought about posting both ways, it's six one way half a dozen the other. (but I won't waste your time with an extra loop, I am still wrapping my brain around them adding that!)

### Alternative version

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ResultFile=_Result.searchresult"
)
DEL /F /Q "%_ResultFile%"
SET /P "_SearchTerm=Enter search term: "

ECHO Searching for %_SearchTerm% >"%_ResultFile%"
ECHO --------------------------------------------- >>"%_ResultFile%"

FOR /F "Tokens=1* delims=:"  %%A IN ('
  FINDSTR /S /C:"%_SearchTerm%" *.txt
')  DO (
  For /F %%a in ("%%~tA") Do (
      ECHO.%%a %%A:%%B>>"%_ResultFile%"
  )
)
```

Although there really isn't a functional difference between each method, I waffle on whether the 1st or 2nd is more aesthetically pleasing, so it's a coin flip to me on which to write first or whether to write both at all.

That said trying to create a rational for some of the odd comments I received on poking another for posting my code with minor essentially non functional changes, but the core of the code is still the stuff I wrote, and just chose to show the FOR /F method, but then did so in a way that makes an unnecessary 3rd loop.

I think there are some minor benefits to the `FOR /F`, it saves at about 50 characters of code, and while in this case it's really 50/50, there are scenarios where I would definitely choose it as being a bit faster as the next step, although in this case we only have 3 iterations on a match, so I suspect for the current scenario we'd need to have 10s of thousands of matches before we might noticeably affect the outcome.

That said, by adding a 3rd unneeded loop as in the other comment, I suspect any speed benefit was nullified, so.. I'm not sure, at least in the above code I provided there isn't the unneeded loop, so if there is a speed benefit concert try use that instead. :)

Comment: @LotPings Thanks I realized I forgot the delims ane came back to edit itkii

Comment: @Ben Personick I made a batch script for this code and ran it, the result was: Token=1* delims=:" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @Slowspark  It was a Typo, Tokens needs an S at the end `FOR /F "Tokens=1* delims=:"`, I amended above

Comment: I tried both codes and they give the same wanted result, so thank you!

Comment: @Slowspark  Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

To ***not*** insert the file time, you'll need another for to strip it.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\13\SO_57475301.cmd
@ECHO OFF
SET /P "_searchterm=Enter search term: "

(ECHO Searching for %_searchterm%
 ECHO ---------------------------------------------
 FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A IN ('
  FINDSTR /C:"%_searchterm%" *.txt
 ')  DO For %%a in ("%%A") Do For /F %%D in ("%%~ta") do ECHO:%%D %%A:%%B
) >"_Result.searchresult"
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_57475301.cmd
Enter search term: log

> type _Result.searchresult
Searching for log
---------------------------------------------
08/13/2019 Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:29:05.586 loginfo
08/13/2019 Reboot-79_Logfile_001.txt:08:30:05.586 loginfo
```

To have the file name first reorder `ECHO:%%A:%%D %%B`

Comment: How does this logically differ from the answer I provided Other than trivial differences, such as not setting a variable and wrapping all of the ECHOs into the single `>` it seems to be exactly the same code with just minor changes, No?  Am I missing something? I think. biggest change is where I did a coin flip and chose to do a `FOR` with a logical test instead of a second `FOR /F` but they do the same thing, I basically did a coin flip and chose to use `FOR` with the Logical test for design aesthetics, but I suppose its probably going to be faster to use the `FOR /F` on long runs.  ,

Comment: Did you test *your* code? @aschipfl also used a `for /f` to strip off the time - what your code does **not** but output's another line with the time.

Comment: Yes I had a typo `Set` to `="` instead of `=1"` but is essentially exactly the same code, I don;t often get to test these as I mostly write them on my phone, but since I dropped it Sunday this is harder too as it goes white screen off and on, I couldn't even reply to you fully earlier on thanking you for noticing the delims was missing.  That said, I don't see the relevance of how Asc's comment factors into anything.  TBH I looked at the post when it was 12 seconds old and started writing, so the comment wasn't there, but even if it was, of what relevance is it? Both are valid.

Comment: So, it would have been the same coin flip to use one or the other, so again I don't understand, are you just saying "everyone's doing it" ?  It seems apropos of nothing. Also on looking at your code again, you essentially did the same as I've noted, but used a 3rd, unneeded loop, why even use that loop it serves no purpose that I can see, although in that case you would be having output that matches my terms, and maybe you just wanted it to be different looking, then why waste time with a 3rd loop, and instead just change to using a `%%D` in a 2nd loop directly

Comment: What's more I am just comparing them, and it looks like you lifted my code to speed up writing your code, but then why did you add the unneeded extra loop to my code instead of just changing to a `FOR /F` ?  No wonder they are so similar.  Did you think that the issue with the for %%a was because it needed to be parsed twice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get what you want.

=== grepplus.ps1

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:/src/t' -Filter '*.ps1' |
    Select-String '^S' |
    ForEach-Object {
        '{0} {1}:{2}' -f (
             (((Get-ChildItem $_.Path).LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') -replace '-','/'),
             $_.Filename,
             $_.Line
        )
    }
```

=== grepplus.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:/src/t' -Filter '*.ps1' |" ^
        "Select-String '^S' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "'{0} {1}:{2}' -f (" ^
                "(((Get-ChildItem $_.Path).LastWriteTime).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd') -replace '-','/')," ^
                "$_.Filename," ^
                "$_.Line" ^
            ")" ^
        "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475301/findstr-add-date-modified-of-the-files-as-a-prefix-to-each-result#comment101431566_57475301) converted to an answer since I hope it might be useful…

Instead of a simple [`findstr /S`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) command line you could try something with a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) that iterates over the files. To get the file date/time stamps (last modification) and the pure file names you could make use of [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) like `~t` and `~nx`, respectively. To capture the output of `findstr` use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html); then you will be able to concatenate it with other strings.

Something like this could work for you (I hope):

```cmd
(
    for %%I in ("*.txt") do (
        for /F "delims=" %%S in ('findstr /C:"%searchterm%" "%%~I"') do (
            for /F %%T in ("%%~tI") do (
                echo %%T:%%~nxI:%%S
            )
        )
    )
) >> "_Result.searchresult"
```

The second `for /F` loop tries to split off the pure date from the date/time value returned by the `%%~tI` portion, but regard that this value is locale-dependent!

The above approach does not recurse sub-directories to find matching files. Though if you really want to do so, replace the line `for %%I in ("*.txt") do (` by `for /R %%I in ("*.txt") do (`.